# When applying for a British visa, is it necessary to supply a translation of the passport?

Tags: visas, uk, translations

I've read the official advice [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk), which doesn't contain the answer.

The answer is not obvious because as well as having to be presented when applying for visas, passports also need to be presented at the border, where you don't have to supply a translation and immigration officials are trained to assess passports whatever languages they're printed in.

Comment: Most passports are printed in "international" in some form or another; names are usually either romanised and/or printed in two variants, and the fields are often labeled in local language and English. What passport do you have that would be completely unintelligible "internationally"?

Comment: Yes but the same is true of lots of documents and the official advice is that they must be translated if not in English or Welsh. But it's not wholly clear whether or not this applies to passports. In practice few who can read English and hold down an office job will be puzzled by "passeport" or "nom", but this is a question about rules and policy.

Comment: What passport do you have? Most passports' data pages are also in more than one language, usually including English.

Comment: It's not for me. The person's passport doesn't use English. I wouldn't have asked whether it needed to be translated into English if it did.

Comment: We don't particularly care whether it's you or someone else, we're just using "you" because you gave us no other clue. We're also not doubting your sincerity in asking this. But a simple straight answer to our questions would help us answer your question in return.

Comment: The official advice you linked does not say that the passport has to be in English or Translated, it just says that you have to provide your passport.

Comment: You're going to be filling out a form for the application. On that form, you'll be writing your name. Your passport likely just needs to corroborate the name you wrote on the application. As long as the passport contains your name in latin characters as it appears on the application form, the rest is probably not very important. It would need to be an extremely exotic passport for the immigration bureau to require a translation, and in that case they'll probably ask for it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy: how did you make the interpretation that the passport does not have to be in English or translated? The guidance says: "If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office". In the list of supporting documents, the first document listed is: "Travel document (passport)". For each of the listed documents, none of them specifically say they require a translation, because a precondition regarding language has already been set in the introductory paragraphs.

Comment: @deceze, mlc: I don't think the specific issuer of the passport is relevant to OP's question so probing them about it or making it a condition for help is not helpful for OP (and could be interpreted as unhelpful). It's entirely OP's prerogative to share information that could be used to identify them. The question isn't about the intelligibility of a passport, it's about the specificity of requirements set out by UKVI.

Comment: As things stand: 1) UKVI states "If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office". 2) There are passports that don't have English in them ([ICAO Doc 9303 Pt 3 Sec 3.1](https://www.icao.int/publications/documents/9303_p3_cons_en.pdf) recommends the issuer's national/working language and either English, French or Spanish). IIRC Haiti is one example that doesn't include English (Haitian Creole + French). 3) The potential ambiguity arrives as passports don't typically require translations.

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer. I would've interpreted it the same way as OP and (supposing I don't seek further guidance) submitted a translated passport because at best it's actually useful to the caseworker assessing the application and at worst it just satisfies what the guidance says.

Comment: @Wing I’ve sponsored a UK visitor visa three times since 2017 without ever getting the applicant’s passport translated.

Comment: @Wing The machine readable zone in a passport is not written in a human language, passport fields can be directly read from there using a computer, and also for biometric passports, a translation to English is not needed.

Comment: @Traveller did any of those passports lack English as one of its international languages?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy: I don't disagree with that however you said in your original comment, "The official advice you linked does not say that the passport has to be in English or Translated" which is misleading because the advice **does** say (or could be interpreted to say, depending on how strongly you read it) that the passport requires translation if it doesn't contain English or Welsh.

Answer (score 12):

**No**. The contents of [modern machine-readable passports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport) are fully standardized and do not require translation, they can even be read fully automatically.

No, I don't have an official source specifically for UK visas here, but I've never heard of any authority requiring translating a passport for *any* purpose: it's simply unnecessary.

Comment: Exactly, passports are inteded to be used worldwide, they don't need any translation. It's not mentioned in official sources because it's so obvious.

Comment: (+1) I have successfully sponsored a UK visa three times without having the applicant’s passport translated

Comment: @lambshaanxy: Not saying you're wrong because I also think passports typically don't require translation however your answer is only useful for biometric passports which OP and future visitors to this Q&A may not have, especially since not all countries issue biometric passports and some countries only recently started issuing them meaning they'll have a significant number of non-biometric passports in circulation.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko: it's not that passports are intended to be used worldwide that they don't require (additional) translation, it's because they are **designed** to be used worldwide that they have some useful translations already included in them that means they typically don't require translation. [ICAO Doc 9303 Pt 3 Sec 3.1](https://www.icao.int/publications/documents/9303_p3_cons_en.pdf) recommends the issuer's national/working language and either English, French or Spanish.

Comment: @Wing yes, intended AND designed ;-)

Comment: @Wing This applies to machine-readable passports as well, which (AFAIK) every single country in the world issues now.  Biometric passports just add a chip.

Comment: @lamshaanxy This applies to paper passports as well. Passport fields were standardized well before machine-readable passports were thought of.

Comment: @Traveller few countries issue passports using only French and/or Spanish as the international language.

Comment: @david I don't think so. If you look at a 1970's US passport and compare it to a 1970's British passport, the layout is completely different. The UK passport has an occupation field, the complete details for a wife, and is handwritten versus typed. It's the 1980's ICAO machine readable passport that standardizes things.

Comment: @user71659 There was not a formal standard, but a handful of fields were de-facto standard and included (albeit not always in the same locations) on a significant percentage of pre-MRTD passports.

Comment: @lambshaanxy: biometric passports are a subset of machine readable passports. If you meant machine readable passports, that should be referenced in the answer instead of biometric passports.